# Getting the SQL Server Connection Exception

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am getting below connection exception, when trying to connect to SQL Server using JDBC.

Can someone please help, with this issue?

I am using sqljdbc4.jar file to connect to SQL Server

Code is as below

```
String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://10.156.54.123;encrypt=false;DatabaseName=PRA;sslProtocol=TLSv1;";
 String user = "username";
 String pass = "password";
 conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass);
```

This is the exception.

> Nov 14, 2020 8:33:01 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel enableSSL
> INFO: java.security path: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_261-amd64/jre/lib/security
> Security providers: [SUN version 1.8, SunRsaSign version 1.8, SunEC version 1.8, SunJSSE version 1.8, SunJCE version 1.8, SunJGSS version 1.8, SunSASL version 1.8, XMLDSig version 1.8, SunPCSC version 1.8]
> SSLContext provider info: Sun JSSE provider(PKCS12, SunX509/PKIX key/trust factories, SSLv3/TLSv1/TLSv1.1/TLSv1.2/TLSv1.3)
> SSLContext provider services:
> [SunJSSE: KeyPairGenerator.RSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyPairGenerator$Legacy
> aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1]
> , SunJSSE: Signature.SHA1withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$SHA1withRSA
> aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.5, 1.3.14.3.2.29, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.5]
> attributes: {SupportedKeyClasses=java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey|java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey}
> , SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLS -> sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLSContext
> aliases: [SSL]
> , SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLSv1 -> sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLS10Context
> aliases: [SSLv3]
> , SunJSSE: Signature.MD2withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$MD2withRSA
> aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.2, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.2]
> attributes: {SupportedKeyClasses=java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey|java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey}
> , SunJSSE: KeyFactory.RSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory$Legacy
> aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1]
> , SunJSSE: Signature.MD5withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$MD5withRSA
> aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.4, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.4]
> attributes: {SupportedKeyClasses=java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey|java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey}
> , SunJSSE: KeyStore.PKCS12 -> sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore
> , SunJSSE: TrustManagerFactory.SunX509 -> sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl$SimpleFactory
> , SunJSSE: KeyManagerFactory.SunX509 -> sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509
> , SunJSSE: TrustManagerFactory.PKIX -> sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl$PKIXFactory
> aliases: [SunPKIX, X509, X.509]
> , SunJSSE: KeyManagerFactory.NewSunX509 -> sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$X509
> aliases: [PKIX]
> , SunJSSE: SSLContext.Default -> sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext
> , SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLSv1.1 -> sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLS11Context
> , SunJSSE: Signature.MD5andSHA1withRSA -> sun.security.ssl.RSASignature
> , SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLSv1.3 -> sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLS13Context
> , SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLSv1.2 -> sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLS12Context
> ]
> java.ext.dirs: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_261-amd64/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Unexpected rethrowing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the above solution doesn't work for anyone. Try replacing the `sql-jdbc` jar with `mssql-jdbc-8.4.1` jar.

Posting this because the above approach didn't work for me.
The workaround for me on the exception  - The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Unexpected rethrowing" was to replace the jar.

Answer (score 2):

Hey you have to just follow below steps to resolve your issue:---

You just have to:
Go to java folder:---

```
 1)Find file “java.security” in folder “jre\conf\security”
   
    
2)`In this java.security file, find “3DES_EDE_CBC” linked to “jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms”`
    
3)Remove it!
    
    Sample:
    If file "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\jre\conf\security\java.security"
    
    ORIGINAL:
    
    jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024,
    EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL
    
    NEW (after removing “3DES_EDE_CBC”):
    
    jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024,
    EC keySize < 224, anon, NULL
```

Comment: Thank You so much. It is working very fine. Instead of updating the original file, I am passing the file as parameter 

java -Djava.security.properties=<Path of java.security file>

Comment: welcome buddy. yes, you can do like that also but make sure "3DES_EDE_CBC" should not be there.

Comment: It looks like you copied this from somewhere else. Please provide the necessary attribution and link to that source. If this was written by yourself, then please edit it to fix the formatting (normal text does not belong in a code block).

Comment: i am new to this plateform , donno how to decorate text buddy. don't worry i have faced this issue n many more mssql issue

Comment: I had to remove `TLSv1, TLSv1.1` as well from the `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68149843/606662