# Error message "The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences"

Tags: jnlp, kvm, ipmi

I am trying to run this [JNLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start#Java_Network_Launching_Protocol_(JNLP)) file on Windows 10 to connect to a server (actually, I am connecting to a dedicated server via [KVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch#KVM_over_IP_(IPKVM)) over [IPMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface) ([IPKVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch#KVM_over_IP_(IPKVM))) or whatever it is called, so I can install a new operating system).

I am getting error

> The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences.

Is there something I need to do in Java client to fix the error?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unrelenting tls10 objections in my case. So I grabbed jre7 which worked making sure its bin directory had priority.  Was necessary to create an Oracle account to access the [archives](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase7-archive-downloads.html)

Answer (score 83):

Go to folder *C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib\security*.

In file *java.security*, find option *jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms* and delete *TLSv1*.

Comment: For Linux environment the file is in /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/conf/security/java.security

Comment: For Java **64 bits** the PATH is "C:\Program Files\Java\jre...\lib\secutiry\java.security"

Comment: @EytanNaim It's not only for Linux enviroment but for java-11 plus version!

Comment: Probably better @EytanNaim to do `locate conf/security/java.security` -- you might not be on that version of java.

Comment: It's worth noting that one shouldn't be randomly disabling security features: TLSv1 and all the other items in `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` are disabled because they're insecure. In my case, it's a very old SQL Server db that will, I hope, be replaced next month.

Comment: Can't edit it due to non-administrative rights

Comment: The problem ocurred also with JDK **8.0.382-zulu**. The fix is also the same and the path (MacOs Ventura) is _.../8.0.382-zulu/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security_

Comment: I actually had to ultimately change it here as well: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_333\jre\lib\security

Answer (score 18):

It appears that the latest update of [Java 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_11) has disabled [TLS 1.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_1.0) and [TLS 1.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_1.1).

Here is the detailed documentation on how to enable it again: *[TLS 1.0/1.1 changes in OpenJDK and Amazon Corretto](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/tls-1-0-1-1-changes-in-openjdk-and-amazon-corretto/)*

Apparently, I was caught in this issue because of a JDK update today and had hard time finding it. This can help.

Answer (score 11):

The first thing to do: Go to folder `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib\security`. In the `java.security` file, find option `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` and delete `TLSv1`.

If it still doesn't work, make sure that the line:

```
deployment.security.TLSv1=true
```

exists in file `C:\Users\JavaUser\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties`.

Comment: On [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows), presumably. What version was it tested on? [Windows 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10)?

Comment: Under Linux you may find "jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms" under "~/.config/icedtea-web/deployment.properties" and "deployment.security.TLSv1=true" is configured in "/etc/java-*-openjdk/security/java.security"

Comment: Thank you!! the second part of your answer ended up working for me.

Comment: works for me, only with first part, thanks

Comment: I actually had to ultimately change it here as well: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_333\jre\lib\security

Answer (score 6):

Don't update to [Java 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_11). Nowadays [TLS 1.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_1.0) is outdated. The sites using TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 certificates for encryption will be marked as insecure in browsers.

So better to update the [Transport Layer Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) (TLS) version in SQL Server.

Please follow the pages:

- *[Connect to SQL Server TLS 1.2 using DbVisualizer and SSMS](https://ganeshchandrasekaran.com/connect-to-sqlserver-tls-1-2-using-dbvisualizer-and-ssms-script-s-1362438bc949)*
- *[KB3135244 - TLS 1.2 support for Microsoft SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe)*

Answer (score 4):

You can set it in [JRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine#Java_Runtime_Environment) inside [SoapUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoapUI) (if you are using it): Remove "*TLSv1, TLSv1.1*" from "*jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms*" property in file *${soapui_home}/jre/conf/securityjava.security*.

Comment: Removing from jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms did worked for me.

Comment: Then you should restart SoapUI.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Control Panel, Program. Click on Java (Java control Panel), go to *Advanced*, scroll down and check TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1.

Close your program and start it again.

Comment: What platform? [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows)? What version? [Windows 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10)?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a Windows 10 related question, but just in case somebody is looking for an answer. I found this helpful hint [here](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/the-server-selected-protocol-version-tls11-is-not-accepted-by-client-preferences-tls12-ssl20hello/7371/4).

For RedHat based JVMs (e.g. Docker image registry.redhat.io/ubi8/openjdk-11-runtime) you have to remove TLSv1 from the property `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` in:

```
/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/java.config
```

as modifying the `java.security` file alone, will not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse first check the path of jre used by eclipse.
For knowing the path of JRE used by eclipse you can follow the below steps.
(project>properties>java build path> libraries).
click on JRE system library>edit>installed JREs
Now it will display the path of JRE currently used by eclipse.
Go to JRE>conf>security and
open java.security file and remove TLSv1 from the property jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms

Answer (score 0):

the solution look the video for java 11

The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynEQM-W8RkU

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently, it was because I was trying to connect to an old version of Microsoft SQL Server (2012, ver. 11.00.3156) using the latest versión of the SQL Server JDBC Driver (ver. 12.2.0) with a newer versión JDK (ver. 11.0.15).

It happens because newer versión of JDK by default dissable some old security algorithms like TLSv1.0 (in favor of newer like TLSv1.2/TLSv1.3) which the old SQL Server is requiring as security algorithm.

To solve the issue I changed the JDBC driver to an older version 8.2.2 and I had to pass some java security VM options to the JDK to override some security configs and remove TLSV1.0 from the disabled algorithms

VM options to pass to JDK

```
-Djdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL
```

(note that TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1 are removed from the original JDK list)

[image]

Doing that I managed to successfully connect to the old SQL Server 2012. Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

On Linux but, Java being cross platform, I believe the main options I used still apply. I had the same errors as OP and an additional one about a self-signed jar. To use the tool to connect and install/manage the OS:

1. I first downloaded an old JDK and saved it in its own location (`/usr/local/lib/jvm/jre1.8.0_x/`), without adding it to `$PATH`.
   I didn't want the outadted version to be used by default for anything.
2. I ran `/usr/local/lib/jvm/jre1.8.0_x/bin/javaws -viewer`, then escaped out of the cache viewer dialogue, to add the servers to the Exception Site List under the Security tab, e.g. `https://10.24.12.6/`.
   This causes Java to show a warning dialogue rather than blocking the load entirely.
3. I then ran the following command to execute the downloaded `.jnlp`.
   The environment variable is set inline so it's used only for that one run rather than using a global setting or affecting the entire shell.
   In Windows, you probably have to set that environment variable separately, which will affect all subsequent invocations of `java`, `javaws`, etc. in that running shell, but the values should be the same.

   ```bash
   _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1 -Djdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=None -Djdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms=None' /usr/local/lib/jvm/jre1.8.0_x/bin/javaws my-connection-file.jnlp
   ```

Though I'd allowed TLSv1 in the security settings, the client was still refusing to use it, so connections continued to fail.
The `protocols` directives force the client to use the necessary one.

Note the `x` in the paths is the actual version number.

Answer (score -3):

**Problem:** TLS 1.0 is not supported in Java 1.8 and above.
To connect to [SQL Server 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2014) and below servers, you need to send TLS 1.0 connection.

**Solution:** if you downgrade your project to Java 1.7 version this problem will be solved. The [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) driver version you are using should be 4.2.

**Solution for Java 1.7 SSL connection issue:**

You will get an error when you query websites with SSL certificate in Java 1.7 version. To fix this error; Download the site’s .cer certificate. Next (note we are talking about JRE file here), write “keytool” in the carsets file at *%path_java_jre\lib\security*.
Your connection problem will disappear.

Comment: Re *"carsets"*: Do you mean *"charsets"*?