# The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12] how to fix

Tags: java, tomcat

The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]

connecting with sql server with java tomcat server using eclipse

Comment: is the client the webapp running in tomcat or something calling tomcat?

Comment: Beware of outdated and insecure TLS protocols https://stackoverflow.com/a/67804650/2834978

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour], read [ask] and edit your question with detailed steps to reproduce (e.g. a [mcve]) and make sure that there is indeed a question and not just an error message.

Comment: @kamran, Is your JDK version lower than 8?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: webapp is running . I am using java 1.8. I updated jre security file and remove TLS 1.1 . trying to pull data from sql server using java code . using tomcat as server .